# forwardInvocation to nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have an object (A) that needs to work as a proxy to an other object. there is also a condition that when verified should make the object work as nil.

I've implemented:

```
-(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if (condition)
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.object];
    else
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:nil];
}
```

but it's not enough. when the condition is satisfied and a method is called on A `unrecognized selector sent to instance` is raised.

Comment: If the target is nil, why invoke at all?

Comment: basically if a is my proxy. I want c = [a methodB] be either [a.object methodB] or nil, depending on condition. I don't want the application to crash.

Comment: Would NSNull in place of nil work for your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on `invoke` in NSInvocation's class reference:

> You must set the receiver’s target, selector, and argument values before calling this method.

If you haven't set `target` (or have set it to `nil`, which is basically the same thing), you shouldn't be invoking the invocation. If you want to mimic the behaviour of sending a message to nil, you can just return 0/nil - this is the default behaviour of objc_msgSend if the target is nil. If you're interested in seeing why this works, you can have a look [here](http://blog.zhengdong.me/2013/07/18/a-look-under-the-hood-of-objc-msgsend) for an overview of objc_msgSend's implementation (fair warning, it's all in assembly).